# How to set my query for a PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have built a PDO connection and query, now I need it to be safe from SQL Injection

Here is my code

User Input

```
<?php $search=$_GET["Search"];?>
```

SQL that querys DB

```
<?php
// Issue the query
$Recordset1 = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM catelogue 
WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE '$search'");
$Recordset1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Fetch The rows

```
<?php $row_Recordset1 = $Recordset1-> fetch(); ?>
```

After this there is a table with a do-while loop to display everything that was returned

How do I make a prepared statement for my query?

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok That last bit of code that DavdRew posted helped to get my search working again. Now I have 2 new problems.

Problem 1: After doing a few querys I get this message

mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: MySQL server has gone away

It still shows the rest of my page with what I searched for. How is this fixed?

Then Problem 2:

With every search the first record returned is empty, a blank record. It never did this before, Why is it doing it now?

Many Thanks DavdRew

EDIT: ADDED MORE CODE

THIS IS THE ENTIRE PDO CODE

```
<?php 

$hostname_EchosPDO = "localhost";
$username_EchosPDO = "echos";
$password_EchosPDO = "echos";
$database_EchosPDO = "full catelogue";
$connStr = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=full catelogue';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($connStr, $username_EchosPDO, $password_EchosPDO);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    } 
?>


<?php


$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE ?"); // prepare statement
if ($q->execute(array('sharpay%'))) // execute wirh passed params array($search)
{
    $row_Recordset1 = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // store fetched result into $rows;

}
else
{
    $error = $dbh->errorInfo();
    throw new Exception("SQLSTATE: {$error[0]}. {$error[1]} {$error[2]}");
}


?>
<?php /* $row_Recordset1 = $Recordset1-> fetch(); */ ?>


<?php do { ?>
<table width="800" border="0">
          <tr>
          <form action="/Echos Online/Detail.php" method="get"><input value='<?php echo $row_Recordset1['CAT NO.']; ?>' name="detail" type="hidden"/><td width='100' rowspan='4'><input type="image" img src="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['IMAGE PATH']; ?>" width="<?php if ($row_Recordset1['FORMAT']=='DVD') {echo "70";} else if ($row_Recordset1['FORMAT']=='DVD+CD') {echo "70";} else if($row_Recordset1['FORMAT']=='BLURAY+CD') {echo "81";}else if($row_Recordset1['FORMAT']=='BLURAY+DVD') {echo "81";} else if($row_Recordset1['FORMAT']=='BLURAY') {echo "81";} else {echo "100";} ?>" height="100"></td></form>
            <td width="100">Artist:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['ARTIST']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100">Title</td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['TITLE']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100">Format</td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['FORMAT']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100">Cat. No.</td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['CAT NO.']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <hr background-color="#e4a566" color="#e4a566"; width="100%"/>
  <?php }  while ($row_Recordset1 = $q-> fetch());  ?>
</table>
```

Honestly now I'm at the piont of going back to preg_replace and mysql_real_escape_string

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post a piece if code here, of how you make and fetch query, and how you ouput it.

Comment: First of all try [this](http://bogdan.org.ua/2008/12/25/how-to-fix-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-2006.html) to fix first one. And please, describe more about second problem.

Comment: After `$row_Recordset1 = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` just do `<?php foreach ($row_Recordset1 as $row): ?>` here your html and then `<?php endforeach; ?>`, I think the problem is about fetching few times...

Comment: Look for the last code listing in my answer. This should work. After `$rows = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` You have array of all records retrived by query. Then you need just to do simple `foreach ($rows as $row) {}`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$q = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

$data = array();
if ($q->execute($params)) // params is the array of values for each '?' in your prepared statement.
    $data = $q->fetchAll($fetch);
else
{
    $error = $this->pdo->errorInfo();
    throw new \Exception("SQLSTATE: {$error[0]}. {$error[1]} {$error[2]}");
}

return $data;
```

Keep in mind that `WHERE IN` **works bad**, you need to put as much `?` into you imploded by `,` and wrapped with `IN (` from left and `)` right.
Example:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table AS m WHERE m.id = ?');
if ($statement->execute(array(24))) // here you can pass values too.
     $data = $q->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
else
     exit('Shit happens');
```

This search for record with `id = 24;`

For your code, that would be:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE ?"); // prepare statement
if ($q->execute(array($search))) // execute wirh passed params array($search)
{
    $rows = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // store fetched result into $rows;
}
else
{
    $error = $dbh->errorInfo();
    throw new Exception("SQLSTATE: {$error[0]}. {$error[1]} {$error[2]}");
}
```

Output:

```
<table width="800" border="0">
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <form action="/Echos Online/Detail.php" method="get"><input value='<?php echo $row['CAT NO.']; ?>' name="detail" type="hidden"/><td width='100' rowspan='4'><input type="image" img src="<?php echo $row['IMAGE PATH']; ?>" width="<?php if ($row['FORMAT']=='DVD') {echo "70";} else if ($row['FORMAT']=='DVD+CD') {echo "70";} else if($row['FORMAT']=='BLURAY+CD') {echo "81";}else if($row['FORMAT']=='BLURAY+DVD') {echo "81";} else if($row['FORMAT']=='BLURAY') {echo "81";} else {echo "100";} ?>" height="100"></td></form>
            <td width="100">Artist:</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ARTIST']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Title</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['TITLE']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Format</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['FORMAT']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Cat. No.</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['CAT NO.']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <hr background-color="#e4a566" color="#e4a566"; width="100%"/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: So I assign my sql a varible and then put this in place of the old query?

Comment: Look at the second code listing, you pass query with `?` in the place of you variables, and as the second arg give array of values to replace `?` in your query. Then execute, and if it's all ok - fetch.

Comment: Ok so I think I'm getting the hang of this but now I get this error

Comment: Warning: PDO::exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: I don't see any of that in my example, what's for you need `::exec()` method? `$q = $pdo->prepare('SQL with ? ? ? as places for vars'); if ($q->execute(array($v1, $v2, $v3))) return $q->fetchAll();`

Comment: That was my mistake, I think that you can pass values for the prepared statement only in `->execute($params);` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $username, $password);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE :search');
$stmt->bindValue('search', $search);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

OR 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE catelogue.TITLE LIKE :search');
$stmt->execute(array('search' => $search);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

note that you probably want to have your $search string wrapped with wildcard characters, like

```
$stmt->bindValue('search', '%'.$search.'%');
```

also note that searching using like wont use index if you have wildcard on left side of like criteria

```
$stmt->bindValue('search', '%'.$search.'%'); //will not use index
$stmt->bindValue('search', $search.'%'); //will use index
```